# C# change image on button press in a windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows

I know how to put an image into a picture box and have it show up with the press of a button, but how would I change the image with the press of the same button? Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace HuntersApp
{

    public partial class TracksPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public TracksPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string[] imageArray = new string[] { "/Images" };
        private void nextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {   

        }

        private void previousButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tracksImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/cottontail55.jpg",UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want to do. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Basically I display one image on clicking the nextButton, which I know how to do. What I want is to be able click through different images using the next button, and the user can stop and look at any picture they want or keep going through and looking at different images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an array of all the images in your class and a variable that increments like this:

```
public partial class TracksPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    string[] imagePaths = new string[] { "/path/to/image1.jpg",
                                         "/path/to/image2.jpg",
                                         "/path/to/image3.jpg",
                                         "/path/to/image4.jpg",
                                         "/path/to/image5.jpg" };
    int i = 0;
    .
    .
    .
```

Then in your `previousButton_Click()` function:

```
private void previousButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tracksImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePaths[i], UriKind.Relative));

    i = i == 4 ? 0 : i + 1; // Change 4 to the number of images you have + 1. In this example, I assume 5 images.
}
```

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to keep going to next image on `nextButton_Click`, here's how you can do it.

```
string[] imageArray = new string[] { "url1", "url2" }; //This array contains URI strings
private counter = 0; //This denotes index of array

private void nextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    tracksImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageArray[counter], UriKind.Relative));
    counter++;
}
```

Of course, you will have to take care of counter not exceeding the length of array.

Also, bonus: please stick to .Net naming conventions. Names are written in pascal case instead of camel case here. So, it would be `TracksImage` and `NextButton` and so on! [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) are more details.